# How do I set up a contract for a IT company's logo?

Tags: working-from-home

So I'm kinda new on the whole 'do works for companies' thing, I'm artist, have been drawing for the past 6y and mostly I do art from person to person, but I was approached by a client who wanted to have me draw a logo for his IT company.

Since this is my first time doing a commission for a company, I have literaly no idea how to go from that. From what I've been told I need to be pretty specific about it in contracts, about such things as if they get profits out of the art, and so on...

Basically what I'm asking is. What do I do, and how do I proceed? And yeaaah I don't have money or a known lawyer to ask help about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Logos** are different than other artwork.

Yes you need a contract. However, it is **not** customary for the artist to retain *any* rights or have any stipulations on usage for a logo. A company needs to be free to use their logo in *any* instance for *any* purpose. Putting usage restrictions in place for a logotype does nothing but create undue stress - for both you and the client.

In simple terms, a contract for a logo would entail general aspects such as **cost**, amount of **revisions** permitted before additional costs are incurred, **payment** schedules, **indemnity** clauses, **cancellation** fees, and **contingencies** as to *when* rights are transferred (upon full payment) and *what* those right are (all rights in cases of logos).

It is customary to merely *transfer **all** rights* to the artwork once payment *in full* has been received where logo design is concerned. So, keep the contract simple and straight-forward. No need to muddy it up with usage and royalty issues.

Logotypes also generally entail providing native files (vector .ai files) which is also different than other artwork most of the time.

Different stack, but these may be helpful:

- [Copyright on free work](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/54182/3270)
   ("free" doesn't really matter in this context)
- [Is it inappropriate to ask for royalties on a logo design if the client decides to print the logo on products and sell them?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/42464/3270)